# Cannot delete LUIS account

Tags: azure-language-understanding

When I signed up for the LUIS service I did not created a Azure resource in my Azure subscription but get the default one, this resource is located in west us and not connected to my azure subscription.

I tried to create new resource but cannot select west europe but only west us.

I then tried to delete my account from the profile > user settings but without success, I get signed out but when signing in again the account still exists.

How do I delete my LUIS account and create a new one with the same login?

Comment: I think they we moving to requiring an authoring resource in Azure for the LUIS app, but I'm not sure how to delete it if you do not have one...

Comment: @Kalle for creating a new LUIS account, I would suggest you to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-get-started-create-app#sign-in-to-luis-portal. Can you elaborate on how you created the resource in the first place?

Comment: @ranusharao I followed the steps described in the documentation you are referring to but int step 4, I selected the option "Continue using your trial key".

Comment: when you try to delete the account, do you get any error on the page or n the Dev Console?

Comment: no error, I get signed out from the LUIS website, but if I try to sign in again later the account is still there.

Comment: Have you tried with the preview portal 'https://preview.luis.ai' ?